# .NET core app to send email and deploy on docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, sendmail

I need to develope send email service using .NET core and deploy it on docker.
What is the best nuget package to use.
And is FluentEmail.Core supported on Linux platform,

Comment: [MailKit](http://www.mimekit.net/) is a popular one.  I have used it on multiple projects.